# Getting "ReferenceError: process is not defined" in React-Typescript video-chat App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, socket.io, webrtc

Actually, I am working on a React Typescript project for making a video chat web app using React with Typescript, webRTC, and socket.io, everything is working to be fine but there is a function in my code to which I am calling on button click and that function is `leaveCall()` and on calling this function I am getting an error which I am unable to understand and the error is like this:

```
process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at emitReadable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116743:5)
    at onEofChunk (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116722:5)
    at readableAddChunk (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116493:5)
    at Readable.push (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:116481:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:123896:44
```

I don't know where this error is coming from because I am not using any `process` in my code so can someone help me?
Below is my front-end code using which I am handling all the video-chat functions:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer, { SignalData } from 'simple-peer';

interface CallData {
  isReceivingCall: boolean;
  from: string;
  name: string;
  signal: SignalData;
}

interface SocketContextProps {
  call: CallData | undefined;
  callAccepted: boolean;
  myVideo: React.RefObject<HTMLVideoElement>;
  userVideo: React.RefObject<HTMLVideoElement>;
  stream: MediaStream | undefined;
  name: string;
  setName: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  callEnded: boolean;
  me: string;
  callUser: (id: string) => void;
  leaveCall: () => void;
  answerCall: () => void;
}

const SocketContext = createContext<SocketContextProps>({} as SocketContextProps);

const socket: Socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

const ContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream>();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [call, setCall] = useState<CallData | undefined>(undefined);
  const [me, setMe] = useState('');

  const myVideo = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const userVideo = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const connectionRef = useRef<Peer.Instance>();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        if (myVideo.current) {
          myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
        }
      });

    socket.on('me', (id: string) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }: CallData) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);

  const answerCall = () => {
    setCallAccepted(true);

    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data: SignalData) => {
        socket.emit('answerCall', { signal: data, to: call?.from });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream: MediaStream) => {
      if (userVideo.current) {
        userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      }
    });

    if (call?.signal) {
        peer.signal(call.signal);
      }


    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const callUser = (id: string) => {
    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data: SignalData) => {
      socket.emit('callUser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream: MediaStream) => {
      if (userVideo.current) {
        userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      }
    });

    socket.on('callAccepted', (signal: SignalData) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);

      peer.signal(signal);
    });

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const leaveCall = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);
    connectionRef.current?.destroy();
    window.location.reload();
  };

  const socketContextValue: SocketContextProps = {
    call,
    callAccepted,
    myVideo,
    userVideo,
    stream,
    name,
    setName,
    callEnded,
    me,
    callUser,
    leaveCall,
    answerCall,
    };
    
    return (<SocketContext.Provider value={socketContextValue}>
    {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>);
    };
    export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

Actually, the above code was in js and the app was simply working fine but as per my need I had to convert it into typescript and so the above error started coming. I have converted the above js code in typescript using chatGPT and I have given the error to chatGPT also but it is of no use so please help me.
And also if you want my server code then here it is below this line:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';

const SocketContext = createContext();

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [call, setCall] = useState({});
  const [me, setMe] = useState('');

  const myVideo = useRef();
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      });

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);

  const answerCall = () => {
    setCallAccepted(true);

    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('answerCall', { signal: data, to: call.from });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    peer.signal(call.signal);

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const callUser = (id) => {
    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('callUser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    socket.on('callAccepted', (signal) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);

      peer.signal(signal);
    });

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const leaveCall = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);

    connectionRef.current.destroy();

    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{
      call,
      callAccepted,
      myVideo,
      userVideo,
      stream,
      name,
      setName,
      callEnded,
      me,
      callUser,
      leaveCall,
      answerCall,
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently. It is happening because the library simple-peer is designed to work in backend as well as frontend but if you want to use it in frontend, you'll need to use browserify or use the minified version of the script directly available on their github repo. The official [github repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer#install) has the information for installation.

Note, you will need to use SimplePeer instead of Peer when using the script.

I was able to import SimplePeer directly from the script in development server but I faced issue while building the react app, so I used CDN from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/simple-peer) and added it in the index.html. After that I used below code to import SimplePeer.

```
const SimplePeer = window.SimplePeer;
```